# How to build an array given a dynamic list of variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Given a very long list of colors, for now let's say 3:

```
["red", "green", "blue"]
```

How can I iterate over a string and do the following, match XXXX and return a string for each color type

```
sentences = Array.new
master_sentence = "This is a XXXX ball"

sa.push("This is a XXXX ball")
```

Where sentences now contains:

```
"This is a red ball"
"This is a green ball"
"This is a blue ball"
```

Comment: What is a "dynamic list of variables"? And where is that dynamic list of variables in your code? Also, what does this have to do with [tag:ruby-on-rails] or the weirdly specific [tag:ruby-on-rails4]?

Comment: just go through docs you don't need to ask all these simple questions on stack overflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate by using `map`:

```
array = ["red", "green", "blue"]
master_sentence = "This is a XXXX ball"

array.map {|color| master_sentence.gsub(/XXXX/, color)}
=> ["This is a red ball", 
    "This is a green ball", 
    "This is a blue ball"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
 a = ["red", "green", "blue"]
=> ["red", "green", "blue"]
 a.map{|x| "This is a #{x} ball"}
=> ["This is a red ball", "This is a green ball", "This is a blue ball"]
```

Comment: I appreciate this, the problem with this answer is the sentence needs to be handled dynamically as seen in the other answer.

Comment: I see, i misunderstood.